# Using ES6 import and export default inside webpack.config

Tags: import, webpack, ecmascript-6

I would like to be able to use es6 imports and export default inside my webpack.config. If I run my webpack like this.

**webpack.config.js**

```
"webpack": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js"
```

I get an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` whick is expected. Then I found on other questions solution that seemed to work for a lot of people. Renaming file to webpack.config.babel.js and including babel-register. I tried that 
**webpack.config.babel.js**

```
"webpack": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node -r babel-register node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --config=webpack.config.babel.js"
```

but now I get this error

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I tried a lot more combinations with babel-node and babel-register but nothing seems to work. I am on windows 10. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running webpack directly, without `babel-register`:

```
"webpack": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --config=webpack.config.babel.js"
```

Also, make sure that in your `.babelrc` file you have the `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` plugin, or if you're using the `es2015` preset, the `modules` option is set to `true`. If you don't want Babel to transpile modules in other situations (for example when making a production bundle), you can tell `babel-loader` not to use `.babelrc` and specify presets manually:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
    babelrc: false,
    presets: [
      ['latest', {
        modules: false,
      }],
    ],
  },
},
```

Comment: Thanks. It works now but I got another problem. My HMR / React hot loader has stopped injecting changes. I have to manually refresh the page to see the change. How is this releated? I use server side rendering.